# Textbox with 5 length of value in asp.net mvc3

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Hello I am using this function code below to automatic add a colon(:) after I entered two numbers in a textbox

```
    function limit(){    
    if (document.getElementById('FitaCorrectionIn1').value.length == 2) {
                document.getElementById('FitaCorrectionIn1').value += ":";
                return false;
            }
return false
    }
```

And here for the max length of 5

```
 <input id="ID" type="text" style="width: 100px" onkeydown="limit()"
                            maxlength="5" />
```

And for my problem # 1 is after the textbox filled with time for example `10:00` I can manage to erase the `00` using the `backspace` and my problem is I want to erase also the added colon using the `backspace` is there any way to solve this?.

For the problem # 2 is for example I want enter a time of `1:00` but the output is `1::00` I need to have a condition for this or any way to solve?.

Comment: Why are you not just using a jquery masked input plugin? (for example - [jquery.inputmask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask))

Comment: @StephenMuecke Can you give me an example?. I'm just starting to learn

Comment: See edited comment

Comment: @StephenMuecke Do I need to Download the js from the site?.

Comment: Download it using the Nuget Package Manager

Comment: after i download it from nuget i get the ff. `inputmask.extensions.js / inputmask.date.extensions.js / inputmask.js / inputmask.numeric.extensions.js / inputmask.phone.extensions.js / inputmask.regex.extensions.js / jquery.inputmask.js.` and i try to drag the `inputmask.js , jquery.inputmask.js` to my .cshtml but now working or i am doing wrong?.

Comment: Read the documentation on the site :)